# Explicit linear object underlying $l$-adic cohomology for almost all $l$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives

If you are working with closed manifolds you can consider cohomology with any coefficients you like but ultimately everything is determined by the singular cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients.

If you are studying the cohomology of varieties you often have to choose a random prime number. Is there a reasonably explicit linear object from which one can recover the $l$-adic cohomology for almost all $l$?

There is the étale topos but it is not linear. There are some candidates for the abelian category of motives but I would not call them explicit. One can also take something like the direct product of $l$-adic cohomology for all $l$ but that feels like cheating.

Comment: Why not taking $R\Gamma(X_{ét},\mathbb{Z})$ (or $R\Gamma(X_{ét},\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$)? Its derived $l$-completion is exactly the étale cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_l$-coefficients and it's exactly as linear as $C_*(X,\mathbb{Z})$ for $X$ a topological space...

Comment: @DenisNardin $\mathbb{Z}$ is the constant sheaf?

Comment: yeah‌‌‌‌‌‌, exactly.

Comment: @DenisNardin I am just surprised why don't number theorists consider that instead of bothering with the $l$-adic representations. Have to think about it.

Comment: @DenisNardin also how does it compare with the singular cohomology when $X$ is a smooth proper complex variety?

Comment: @DenisNardin I don't believe anything like this works, because $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't profinite. This is far more your area than mine, but what do you think $R^1 \Gamma (X_{et}, \mathbb{Z})$ is if $X$ is an elliptic curve?

Comment: Etale cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is essentially a shift of the  $\mathbb{Q/Z}$-one. Thus it is essentially a product over all prime $\ell$. On the other hand, you may apply the fact that the $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-adic cohomology is torsion-free for almost all $\ell$. Thus conjecturally you may recover it from the "Betti numbers" coming from a single prime $\ell$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer It works in the sense that its profinite completion is precisely the product of $l$-adic cohomology for all $l$. Of course the rational part of the fracture square is somewhat pathological (let alone the part at the characteristic), so I'm not sure exactly of what the single cohomology groups are...

Comment: @DavidESpeyer To speak concretely, if I understand what Mikhail and Denis are saying then $R^i \Gamma(X_{et}, \mathbb Z)$ for $X$ an elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$ is $\mathbb Z , 0 , (\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)^2, (\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ for $i=0,1,2,3$ respectively. You can recover the $\mathbb Z/\ell^n$ cohomology from this by the usual exact sequence and thus the $\ell$-adic cohomology.

Comment: It should be clear from this example why this is not used: It carries the same information as the product over $\ell$ of the $\ell$-adic cohomology, plus a tiny bit more (it "knows" that the $H^0$ all come from the same copy of $\mathbb Z$, but this is obvious), but expressed in a less convenient way - e.g. the information that was contained in the cup product pairing is now contained in some subtler Massey-like product.

Comment: An alternative proposal is to take Lichtenbaum cohomology instead: it should have the same $l$-adic completion when $l$ is prime to the characteristic but its rationalization is better behaved.

Comment: If you also assume that the Tate conjecture is valid (and your base field is finitely generated) then the category of motives with $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-coefficients embeds into $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-adic Galois representations; this is probably sufficient to "control" $\ell'$-adic cohomology (also) for $\ell'$ distinct from $\ell$ and $p$.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks. I'll stare at this a bit. One thing that seems odd to me is that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $\lim_{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$; I am used to etale cohomology being the inverse limit $\lim_{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ over coefficients.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer It's a bit confusing but the derived profinite completion of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a shift of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: @DavidESpeyer One thing to think about is that the group cohomology of $\mathbb Z/n \times \mathbb Z/n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ maps to the etale cohomology of $E$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, by taking a $\mathbb Z/n \times \mathbb Z/n$-covering of $E$. Because this is a map into the etale cohomology, when we take a limit over $n$ here, we need a forward limit.