# Étale Poincaré duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let's say a scheme $X$ satisfies Poincaré duality if there is an integer $d\geq 0$ such that for $i>d$ we have $H^i(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}})=0$ and for $0\leq i \leq d$ cup product $H^i(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}})\otimes H^{d-i}(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}})\to H^d(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ is an isomorphism.

Smooth proper schemes over separably closed fields satisfy Poincaré duality but what else? Is there a more general theorem?

Comment: $X=\mathbb{G}_m^r$ should work. (A few corrections: You  should take finite (prime to char k) coefficients, and put in appropriate Tate twists. )

Comment: What is $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: @abx sheafification of the presheaf assigning $\mathbb{Z}$ to everything

Comment: Then, could you give a reference for "smooth proper schemes over separably closed fields satisfy Poincaré duality"? I have serious doubts...

Comment: @Irena Etale Cohomology with coefficients in your sheaf is somewhat pathological. In positive characteristic $H^2(A^1,\mathbb{Z})$ would be non finitely generated. So I’m not sure what duality would mean. Anyway, I deleted my answer, since it doesn’t answer your actual question.

Comment: @DonuArapura don't you just get a compatible duality for $l$-adic cohomology for all primes $l$? Something like this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366773/explicit-linear-object-underlying-l-adic-cohomology-for-almost-all-l

Comment: @velko I hadn't see that question, but you will get something more complicated than a product of $\ell$-adic cohomology...